Launch MS Access from C# using Process.Start()
I am trying to launch MS Access and open a specified database from C# using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start().
string appPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
appPath = $"{appPath}\\DB Application";
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\MSACCESS.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = System.IO.Path.Combine($"{appPath}", "DB.accdb");
process.Start();

When this code gets run in a .NET Core 6 console app, I get these two messages.
"The command line you used to start Microsoft Access contains an option that Microsoft Access doesn't recognize. Exit and restart Microsoft Access using valid command-line options."
I click on Ok and then I get this message box.
"Microsoft Access can't find the database file 'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\DB.mdb'
Microsoft Access launches after these two messages but the .accdb file does not open.
Do I need to specify a switch or different argument?
R

You have DB.accdb in process and DB.mdb in response. What is appPath value?

You're missing double quotes in the file path since you have a white space in the folder name. Try this:
process.StartInfo.Arguments = Path.Combine($"\"{appPath}", "DB.accdb\"");

